# Javaee Jboss j_security_check login always fails

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, j-security-check

I want to do a simple j_security_check Login for my Java EE project, I found this [Tutorial](https://www.examsmyantra.com/article/119/javaee/form-based-login-authentication-in-javaee7-with-wildfly-and-mysql) to set it up with WildFly Server but could not yet get it to work. Everytime I try to login, I get redirected to the error page.

Here is my code stuff:

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
  <security-domain>testDSSS</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>test123.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>administrator</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/pages/admin/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>PUT</http-method>
          <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>user</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/user/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
          <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>testDSSS</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/pages/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/pages/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
      <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    </security-role> 
    <security-role>
      <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role> 
</web-app>
```

login.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <form action="j_security_check" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Username:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="" name="j_username" placeholder="Username" />     
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="" name="j_password" placeholder="Password" />     
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>        
        </div></div>
        </form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

WildFly standalone_full.xml code I added for Security configuration

```
<security-domains>
                <security-domain name="testDSSS" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/testDSSS"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role, 'Roles' FROM users WHERE username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password from users WHERE username=?"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/testDSSS"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role, 'Roles' FROM users WHERE username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password from users WHERE username=?"/>
                        </policy-module>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
```

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: look for your server log if log level is not enough for you then configure your loggers. Or you can debug your code to see what is going on but it will be much more cumbersome than looking for log output. And when you ask questions try to give much detail like what is the output when you run with this conf

Comment: Please add the details of your database schema, which typically consists of three tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. For my situation it turn out the SQL queries (rolesquery and principalsquery) in standalone-full.xml were incorrect as I dont use the column names username and password, but something different.